# Filter on a nested structure in Scala

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have a nested structure in scala and I want to filter this structure but not sure how I can do it:
the main structure is

```
currentCustStory = new CustStory(custEvent.custId, custEvent.eventType, custEvent.eventTime.toLong, currentEventStory)
currentEventStory = new mutable.MutableList[StoryEvent]
```

`storyEvent` has 4 attributes.

I want to filter some elements from `currenteventstory` (a list that belongs to  `currentcustStory`) and create a new `currentcustStory` with elements of Story event that pass the filter.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?
p.s: I am very newbie in Scala

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
val newCurrentEventStory = currentCustStory.currentEventStory.filter(func(x) => Boolean)
val newCustStory = new CustStory(custEvent.custId, custEvent.eventType, custEvent.eventTime.toLong, newCurrentEventStory)
```

You have to figure out what func(x) should be, but it is a function taking one StoryEvent argument and returning true or false. Technically its type is:

```
func(storyEvent: StoryEvent):Boolean
```

Based on the latest information you provided, I think it would be best to do the filtering with a for comphresion because it makes the code easier to understand, debug and modify. Here is an implementation assuming the first element of currentCustStory.currentEventStory passes if its distance < 60:

```
val newCurrentEventStory = new MutableList[StoryEvent]()
val ces = currentCustStory.currentEventStory
var p = false // records if previous element passed

// filter currentCustStory.currentEventStory and build newCurrentEventStory
for (i <- 0 to (ces.length - 1)) {
  if (i == 0) {
    if (ces(0).distance < 60) {
      p = true
      newCurrentEventStory += ces(0)
    } else p = false
  }
  if (p == true) {
    if (ces(i).distance < 60 || ces(i - 1).TimeFromRoot < 90) {
      p = true
      newCurrentEventStory += ces(i)
    } else p = false
  }
}

val newCustStory = new CustStory(custEvent.custId, custEvent.eventType, custEvent.eventTime.toLong, newCurrentEventStory)
```

Comment: in my filter function i need to get the entire list. basically I am flagging each member of a list based on two conditions:[ a) if  currentEventstory(i-1) pass the filter, currentEventStory(i) can also pass the filter if currentEventstory(i).distnace<60 ]OR [b) if currentEventstory(i-1) .TimeFromRoot<90]

Comment: that means each currentEventstory(i) evaluation depends on the previous member evaluation result, is there a way to implement this nested dependency filter ? or pass the entire list to the filter function?

Comment: For evaluating a list element based on the previous element a method is to zip the list with its tail giving a list of tuples, for example List(1,2,3).zip(List(1,2,3).tail) ==  List((1,2), (2,3)), then you can filter such tuples which in your case are in the form (currentEventstory(i-1), currentEventstory(i)).  What is your method for deciding if currentEventstory(0) should pass?

Comment: so I was trying to implement it the way you did but it was giving me a null pointer exception

Comment: it has something to do with Scala lazy evaluation. I guess this way the object has not been constructed yet but I was trying to use it. now I have a function in my custStory class and I am calling it like this:var  windowedRDD2 = windowedRDD.filter(r => r != null).map(a=>a.churnPeriod(isInChurnPeriod,isInChurnMode)) when windowrdd is a rdd of custstory. However this does not work either, in churn period class I am trying to  chang eventstory for each custStory. but it does not work

Comment: so here is my new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246628/changing-an-attribute-in-an-object-that-belongs-to-rdd with scala. its the same code but the way that I went to resolve it does not work!

Comment: @Erin it is not obvious to me what is causing the null exception. Lazy eval means eval should be done just in time implying the result of that eval is null.  Suggest trying not to initialize objects with null in the first place and code to avoid null results using Option[T].  Also suggest tagging your new question with spark.

Comment: @Erin - lazy can be used only with value (val) definitions and causes such definitions to be evaluated only when the value is first accessed during which the evaluation will block the current thread until it is done and the evaluation may result in a null value without exception.